# what is a uniform random number?

Tags: java, random

I am reading a computer science book where there is an exercise asking for writing a java program to print five **uniform** random numbers between 0 and 1.

I know what a random number is and how to generate one in java.

But, what does uniform mean?

Comment: Web search: [`uniform random number`](https://www.google.com/search?q=uniform+random+number) --- Sample Result: *"The Uniform Random Number block generates [**uniformly distributed**](https://www.google.com/search?q=uniformly+distributed) random numbers over an interval that you specify"* and *"uniform distribution refers to a probability distribution for which all of the values that a random variable can take on **occur with equal probability**."*

Comment: @Andreas answered perfectly. A simple web search would've easily given you the answer.

Comment: @Andreas that is a mathematical definition. I can't understand it clearly.

Comment: With normal 6-sided dice, each number 1 to 6 has equal chance to be up, so it is *uniformly random*. If it is a weighted die, also called a loaded die or a crooked die, that is made to have e.g. the number 6 occur more often (or always), then it is not *uniformly random* anymore. ---  [Uniform](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uniform): *Of the same form with others; conforming to one rule or mode*

Answer (score 5):

It's just a random number where each possible number is just as likely as any other possible number.  A fair die is a uniform random number generator for numbers between 1 and 6 inclusive.  A weighted die is a random number generator, but not uniform.